# What is the meaning of "^" in the CPU window of the Immunity debugger?

Tags: disassembly, immunity-debugger

I can't figure out the meaning of `^` in the CPU window of the immunity debugger. What does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it shows the direction of the jump (backwards in this case).